# Two different return types in if else statement in data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-resources

I am trying to set text in `TextView` using data binding. I am using if else statement and if the value is true I want to set String to that `TextView` and in the other case I want to assign id of the String resource. My Code:

```
android:text="@{object.isTrue ? object.getString : object.getStringId}"
```

But when I try to do it I get error that Integer cannot be converted to String.

Everything is alright when I try to assign this String resource it directly like this:

```
android:text="@{object.getStringId}"
```

Is it somehow possible to use in that if else statement two different return types?

Comment: post the code you already started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Context.getString() on the second one, so that both are a String. I think this should work:

```
android:text="@{object.isTrue ? object.getString : context.getString(object.getStringId)}"
```

You don't have to import context, it's auto imported.